# How can I win as a wizard that can't do magic?

Tags: desktop-dungeons

Part 5 of the "Complicated Tasks" quest series instructs you to win the Berserker Camp dungeon as a wizard...  ***without using any glyphs***.  The primary feature of berserkers is that when they are reduced to less than 50% of their health, they start doing double damage.  So the boss does about 200 damage when berserked,  and he has two levels of death protection to boot.  What can I do in terms of preparations, race selection, and general strategy in order to have a shot at surviving this as a magic-less wizard?

My random thoughts: Bear mace would help take out one level of death protection.  A badge of courage would allow you to survive one berserked blow.  But regardless of how high you get your damage, you need to survive at least two berserked attacks, so it seems to be required that you have enough hit points/resistances to survive a berserked attack.  Dracul  + armor?  Dracul's healing boon would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that many people are having this problem.

While I do not play this game, I feel this maybe the droid you are looking for. [A Thread from QCF](http://www.qcfdesign.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1003)

Re: Complicated Tasks part 5 help!
by FDru on Sun Oct 09, 2011 7:19 pm

I did a few test runs in hobbler's hold, seeing if this was only happening with certain glyphs. I didn't find one in particular but I did notice that I wasn't getting Warmonger if I picked up any glyphs. **Converting them from the ground seems to always work.**